# How to get access key and secret for Pitney Bowes APis on Bluemix console?

Tags: ibm-cloud, pitney-bowes

Created account on Bluemix and tried subscribing Apis from Pitney Bowes, I am not able to get the key/secret to call Apis.
Trouble finding them from environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to get the Pitney Bowes API Key and Secret:

1. In the IBM Cloud dashboard open your Pitney Bowes service instance
2. Then, click on the `Open Dashboard` button to open Pitney Bowes developer hub
3. In the Pitney Bowes developer hub select the `My Account` tab and scroll down to bottom of the page to see your API Key and Secret